# Volume of the solid above the parabolic cylinder $z=1-y^2$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, 3d

Find the volume of the solid bounded above by the Parabolic cylinder $z=1-y^2$ and below the plane $2x+3y+z+10=0$ and on the sides of circular cylinder $x^2+y^2-x=0$

Since this is region obtained by three surfaces, i am unable to find out the limits of integration. My question is, in $3D$ plotter i observed that the parabolic cylinder and the circular cylinder are meeting.

But how to solve the equations $x^2+y^2-x=0$ and $z=1-y^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $x^2+y^2-x=(x-\frac12)^2 +y^2-\frac14=0$. Recenter the circle with $x-\frac12=u$ and integrate the volume over the disk $u^2+y^2=\frac14$

$$\int_{u^2+y^2<\frac14} [(1-y^2)-( -2x-3y-10)]dudy \\
=\int_{u^2+y^2<\frac14} (2u+3y-y^2 +12)dudy 
=\int_{u^2+y^2<\frac14} (12-y^2)dudy \\
=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{1/2} (12-r^2 \sin^2\theta)rdr d\theta =\frac{191\pi}{64}\\
$$